# How do you save Stargazer outputs to file in Python?

Tags: python, stargazer

I'm looking for a way to save outputs from Stargazer to file akin to savefig for pyplot outputs. I tried savefig but Stargazer does not seem to have this function.

I turned a regression model into Stargazer form. I'm able to get the visual all and well but am unable to save it to file. The method I found ([Python Stargazer LaTeX output unusable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67030470/python-stargazer-latex-output-unusable)) outputs  a file but I'm unable to open it.
I have a Stargazer outputfile names 'stargazer_tab'

This is my code:

```
file_name = "model1.png" #Include directory path if needed
tex_file = open( file_name, "w" ) #This will overwrite an existing file
tex_file.write( stargazer_tab.render_latex() )
tex_file.close()
```

I end up with a file tht can't be opened.

Comment: You're writing tex data to a .png file, they're not the same thing. If you look at the comment in the thread you linked you can see that the answer you got your code block from is using a .tex output. It also explains that you then have to render that output in some LaTeX file.